# C++ Класс Binary перегрузка оператора "+"

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, binary

У меня задание реализовать класс `Binary` и перегрузить в классе оператор `+`. Я это реализовал, но при выводе выдает неправильный результат. При этом, когда я вызываю метод, все срабатывает правильно. Подскажите, как исправить оператор.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Binary
{
   private:
      string a; //string b;string k;
   public:
      Binary()
      {
          a = "0"; //b ="0";
      }
      Binary(string num1)
      {
          a = num1; //b= num2;
      }
      Binary operator+(const Binary& bnr)
      {
          //k = "";
         //Binary& k;
         int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = a.size() - 1;
         while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
         {
             c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
             c += j >= 0 ? bnr.a[j --] - '0' : 0;
             a = char(c % 2 + '0') + a;
             c /= 2;
         }
         return Binary(a);
     }
     string addBinary(string a, string b)
     {
         string s = "";
         int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
         while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
         {
            c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
            c += j >= 0 ? b[j --] - '0' : 0;
            s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
            c /= 2;
         }
         return s;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Binary& b);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Binary& b)
{
   os << b.a;
   return os;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
   Binary b("1001");
   Binary k("1111");
   cout << b << " " << endl;
   cout << k << " " << endl;
   k = b + k;
   cout << "result\n";
   cout << k << " \n";
   Binary n;
   cout << n.addBinary("1001", "1111");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Н так вы `а` в операторе меняете, в а функции - нет. У оператора также должен быть `const` квалификатор.

Comment: @VTT я пытался делать иначе создавая некий `string k` и его менять но когда я прописываю `return Binary(k)` и потом уже в мейне пытаюсь все это дело вывести то ничего не выводится. `const` не всегда нужен

Comment: `i = a.size() - 1, j = a.size() - 1;` Почему и `i` и `j` инициализируются из `a.size()`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы же в операторе запарываете собственную строку...

```
 a = char(c % 2 + '0') + a;
```

Я бы на вашем месте кое-что изменил (все изменения - в приведенном фрагменте):

```
Binary(const string& num1)
{
    a = num1; //b= num2;
}
Binary operator+(const Binary& bnr) const
{
    return Binary(addBinary(this->a,bnr.a));
}
static string addBinary(const string& a, const string& b)
{
```

Посмотрите **все** изменения.

Answer (score 0):

я не понел  какая цель у вашего класса, но модифицировал, убирая лишнее и ошибки

```
class Binary
{

      string a; //string b;string k;
   public:
      Binary(string num1 = "") : a(num1) {}
      Binary& operator+=(const Binary& bnr)
      {
          //k = "";
         //Binary& k;
         int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = a.size() - 1;
         while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1 //?) 
         {
             c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
             c += j >= 0 ? bnr.a[j --] - '0' : 0;
             a += char(c % 2 + '0'); //?
             c /= 2;        
         }
         return *this;
     }
//     string addBinary(string a, string b)
//     {
//         string s = "";
//         int c = 0, i = a.size() - 1, j = b.size() - 1;
//         while(i >= 0 || j >= 0 || c == 1)
//         {
//            c += i >= 0 ? a[i --] - '0' : 0;
//            c += j >= 0 ? b[j --] - '0' : 0;
//            s = char(c % 2 + '0') + s;
//            c /= 2;
//         }
//         return s; это тоже переписать
//   }
 //   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Binary& b); это не нужно
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Binary& b)
{
   os << b.a;
   return os;
}
```

хотя не смотрел подробно определение функций
оператор + реализуйте вне класса через +=